# Test Result showing null while performing jUnit5 Test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, jersey, junit5

I am writing a jUnit5 test to test my getUserByEmail(String email) using Mockito and when running the test, it is failing.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    
    @Test
    void check_email_existInDB_thenReturn_True() {
        // given - precondition or setup
                UserDetails userdetails2 = new UserDetails(101L, "Anthony Ji", "anthony@gmail.com", "password2");   
                userRepository.save(userdetails2);
                
                // when - action or behaviour that we are going test
                when(userRepository.save(userdetails2)).thenReturn(userdetails2);
                
                // then - verify the result or output using assert statements
                
                assertEquals(userdetails2.getEmail(), userService.getUserByEmail("anthony@gmail.com"));
                //assertTrue(userService.getUserByEmail(userdetails2.getEmail()));
    }
    
    

}
```

This is my interface with extending of JPARepository

```java
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetails, Long>{


}
```

This is my service level class

```java
@Service
public interface UserService {
    
    public Optional<UserDetails> getUserByEmail(String email);
    
    public UserDetails saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails);

}
```

And this is the serviceImpl Class..

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<UserDetails> getUserByEmail(String email) {
        
        List<UserDetails> allUsers = this.userRepository.findAll();
        Optional<UserDetails> userInfo = allUsers.stream().filter(user -> user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(email)).findAny();
        return userInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
        UserDetails savedUserDetails = this.userRepository.save(userDetails);
        return savedUserDetails;
    }

}
```

and finally, this is my controller class while using jersey framework.

```java
@Path(value = "/user")
public class RegistrationResources {
    
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationResources.class);
    
    
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
        
    
    @POST
    @Path("/registration")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerUser(UserDetails userDetails, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        
        logger.info("Inside the registration resource and registering the user");
        boolean isEmailExists = isEmailExists(userDetails.getEmail());
        if(isEmailExists) {
            logger.info("Email Already Registered");
            return Response.status(404).entity("Email Address already registered").build();
            
        }
        else {
            this.userService.saveUserDetails(userDetails);          
            logger.info("User successfully registered");
            return Response.status(200).entity("User successfully registered").build();
        }
                
    }


    public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
        UserDetails userByEmail = this.userService.getUserByEmail(email).orElse(null);
        if(userByEmail == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I tried as above explained in the code.

Comment: 1. Tell us how the test is failing - precise error message is helpful. 2. Controller is irrelevant to the test - please remove to keep the question clear. 3. Your `getUserByEmail` is HUGELY inefficient - you fetch all users from the DB just to pick one. 4. You use both `SpringBootTest` and `MockitoExtension` - they are mutually exclusive - pick one (for service test, pick MockitoExtension) 5. Your setup step in test does nothing - you call unstubed method on a  mock - this is ignored. 6. Your when step does nothing - you stub a method which is not called afterwards. I'm already out of space...

Comment: 1. org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <anthony@gmail.com> but was: <Optional.empty>2. I kept, so, it will be easy to understand anyone3. Then please let me know, how we can check whether that email exist in the DB or not. Because we can’t use findById because we don’t know the id, we only know email.4.As I am new to UNIT TESTING, if you have anything, I can go through it and can update it. Meanwhile, I have removed it from my code.5.How can I correct it?6.How can I correct it?If you have any tutorial please do let me know, And kindly help me in this problem as well.

Comment: First make the query efficient: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa Remember to add an index on the email field in the db.